# VS 2015 compiler can't see a C variable

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors

I'm writing a c++ project with MS Visual Studio 2015. In my project I have to call some variables declared and defined in a C file.

As you can see below, the variables are enclosed within the extern "C" structure:

```
#if defined __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
#endif

GainType MYDLL_API BestCost;      /* Cost of the tour in BestTour */

int MYDLL_API *BestTour;  /* Table containing best tour found */

double MYDLL_API LowerBound;      /* Lower bound found by the ascent */

#if defined __cplusplus
        }
#endif
```

But, however, the compiler isn't able to resolve these three variables. 
I've searched everywhere, i've tried all the proposed solutions, but it still doesn't work.
How can I solve it?

Thanks to everybody!

Comment: How do you compile and link ? Which command line, which files, ...

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the `c` code is in a DLL

For the compiler to find this.

1. Need to define `MYDLL_API` as `__declspec(dllimport)` for C++
2. Need to link with .lib file

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the symbols come from a DLL library. Then you need to add the import library (*.lib) of the DLL to the list of libraries the application is linked with.

In Visual Studio options, this can be done under project properties, Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies (add the lib name there).

Also make sure that the path to the *.lib is set in Linker / General / Additional Library Directories.